# Run jBPM 7.23.0 project on Tomcat 9

Tags: jbpm, tomcat9

I want to deploy jBPM 7.23.0 project on tomcat 9. Is there any document for the same?

I have created the jBPM project using business central and deploy it on WildFly. It is working fine. Now I want to use tomcat instead of WildFly.

Answer (score 0):

There is (are) .war files that can be deployed on Tomcat 9. The files can be downloaded at the [Drools Download page](https://www.drools.org/download/download.html).

> Standalone execution server that can be used to remotely execute rules using REST, JMS or Java interface. Distribution zip contains WAR files for all supported containers [Distribution ZIP](https://download.jboss.org/drools/release/7.23.0.Final/kie-server-distribution-7.23.0.Final.zip).

Latest final version: 7.23.0.Final

There is a readme.md file in the .war that should be checked. There are also instructions in the drools documentation at [7.2.2.1. Tomcat 7.x/8.x](https://docs.optaplanner.org/7.23.0.Final/optaplanner-wb-es-docs/html_single/#_tomcat_7_x8_x) but I think it is outdated.

I've never tried to run in in Tomcat. Springboot, yes, and wildfly, and both of those seem to work just fine. I've also used the CDI version to build a [thorntail version](https://github.com/karlnicholas/kie-thorntail/tree/master/kie-thorntail-samples/jbpm-thorntail-cdi).

Answer (score 0):

Just use the webc version of Distribution:
[KIE tomcat x web container servlet version war](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/kie/server/kie-server/7.25.0.Final/kie-server-7.25.0.Final-webc.war)